# Filter n rows of grouped data frame when different n for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to pick a different number of rows of each group of my data frame.  I haven't figured out an elegant way to do this with dplyr yet.  To pick out the same number of rows for each group I accomplish like this:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    arrange(Sepal.Length) %>%
    top_n(2)
```

But I would like to be able to reference another table with the number of rows I'd like for each group, a sample table like this below:

```
top_rows_desired <- data.frame(Species = unique(iris$Species),
    n_desired = c(4,2,5))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do a `left_join` with 'iris' and 'top_rows_desired' by 'Species', grouped by 'Species', `slice` the `sequence` of `first` 'n_desired' and remove the 'n_desired' column with `select`.

```
left_join(iris, top_rows_desired, by = "Species") %>%
                     group_by(Species) %>% 
                     arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>%
                     slice(seq(first(n_desired))) %>%
                     select(-n_desired)
```

Comment: This looks pretty solid. Any reason why you used left_join instead of inner_join? Both seem like they would work for this example but am I missing something?

Comment: @cylondude `left_join` returns the same number of rows in the first argument i.e left side ('iris') with a new column added for the 'n_desired' from the 'top_rows_desired'.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this answer for those folks who are unable to run the code that [akrun provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795136/5459839). I struggled with this for a while. This answer tackles the issue [#2531 mentioned on github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2531).

You might not be able to run `slice` because you already have `xgboost` loaded in your environment. `xgboost` masks dplyr's `slice` function leading to this issue.

```
Attaching package: ‘xgboost’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

slice

Warning message:
package ‘xgboost’ was built under R version 3.4.1
```

So using

```
detach(package: xgboost)
```

might work for you.

I wasted an hour because of this. Hope this is helpful.